# Atom Editor - Wrapping text with tags using regex

Tags: regex, atom-editor

In Atom, I'm working with a huge text file and I have to wrap all text lines with `<li> </li>`.

For example:

```
ELECTRICAL PRODUCTS

<li>ELECTRICAL PRODUCTS</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem here? Seems very simple. Just capture each line using `(.*)` and replace it with `<li>$1</li>` or `<li>\1</li>` as supported in your editor. Is that what you need? If not, please [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When I find with (.*) and replace with <li>$1</li>, ELECTRICAL PRODUCTS turns into: 

<li>ELECTRICAL PRODUCTS</li><li></li><li></li>

Comment: Looks like your data also has empty lines due to which it is matching empty lines as well and giving you such kind of output. Let me add it as answer to clearly explain.

Comment: Added as answer, please have a look. Although seems like your problem is already solved as you've already accepted an answer. But just have a look in case it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your text file has empty lines which is kind of normal. To not convert empty lines into `<li></li>` form you need to use a regex that doesn't match pure empty lines or lines that only contain spaces as there is no use replacing only space within `<li>` tags. You can better use this regex to match non-empty lines.

```
(\S+(?: +\S+)*)
```

which groups whole line into group1 and then replace it with `<li>$1</li>`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ZxnGM/1)**

As you can see, empty lines as left intact where as all non-empty lines are replaced in `<li>` tags.

Hope this should work well for you. Let me know in case of any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the below sample data..

```
a1sd
1fasd
1fsa
f1sa
f1as
df1
saf1a
sa1
sa
```

All you need to do is find what is the delimiter used in the txt file.. let's say it is linefeed then find \n and replace it with `</li>\n<li>`.. (it may be \n or \r or \r\n)

Then the output will be

```
a1sd</li>
<li>1fasd</li>
<li>1fsa</li>
<li>f1sa</li>
<li>f1as</li>
<li>df1</li>
<li>saf1a</li>
<li>sd1fsf</li>
<li>d1f</li>
<li>sa1</li>
<li>sa
```

you can add manually at the start and end of the file.

```
<li>a1sd</li>
<li>1fasd</li>
<li>1fsa</li>
<li>f1sa</li>
<li>f1as</li>
<li>df1</li>
<li>saf1a</li>
<li>sd1fsf</li>
<li>d1f</li>
<li>sa1</li>
<li>sa</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Group and replace content with following Regex pattern :

```
string li_pattern = @"(?:w+])*+(?<li>[\s\S]*?[;.\n])";
var res = Regex.Replace(text, li_pattern, @"<li>${li}</li>");
```

[https://regex101.com/r/kJFzQr/1][1]